# The Right Javascript code for decimal place in this calculation

Tags: javascript, decimal

How to write this javascript code for the answer to show in the "Total Result in Inches:" box with 3 digits showing AFTER the decimal place?

Any help is appreciated.

Check out full setup here: [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/virtualpea/1rbu4hxy/)

```js
 function calc() {
   var l = parseInt(document.getElementById("length").value);
   var w = parseInt(document.getElementById("width").value);
   var h = parseInt(document.getElementById("height").value);
   var v = (l * w * h / 1728);

   document.getElementById('result').value = v;
 }
```

```css
#calc-container {
  width: 270px !important;
  padding: 5px!important;
  background: #DEEBF7!important;
  margin: 0px 0px 10px 80px!important;
  border-radius: 5px!important;
  -moz-border-radius: 5px!important;
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px!important;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)!important;
  -webkit-box-shadow!important: 0 0 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7)!important;
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 0px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7)!important;
}
```

```html
<div id="calc-container">
  <input id="length" class="calc" size="5" maxlength="5" placeholder="Length" onchange="calc()">x
  <input id="width" class="calc" size="4" maxlength="5" placeholder="Width" onchange="calc()">x
  <input id="height" class="calc" size="5" maxlength="5" placeholder="Height" onchange="calc()">
  <br>Total Result in Cu.Ft.:
  <input id="result" name="result" readonly size="7" style="text-align: center">
</div>
```

Comment: You don’t put `!important` after the property name (`-webkit-box-shadow!important` is syntactically incorrect). And generally… `!important` is pretty bad practice, especially if it’s after _every single_ property.

Comment: thanks xufox. unfortunately, the !important's are there and will probably be removed eventually while other css properties are condensed; i just wanted to put everything up to get a visual of what i'm working with. but could we focus on the javascript for the decimal places please? that's the main thing i need help with. thanks so much

Comment: Your pages has serious accessibility issues, particularly using placeholders instead of labels, that is very bad. Once input is started, the user no longer knows what the field is for. And there is no hint as to the units being used, though I guess they're inches (there is only one country in the world that hasn't gone metric).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your form should be more accessible, with labels for form controls and fieldset to group them. You should validate the input values (not done in the example below), handle errors and check the result before writing to the screen.

There should also be a "calculate" button to make the form update, onchange by itself isn't sufficient. But I'll leave that for you to add.

e.g.

```js
function calc() {
  var form = document.getElementById('volume');
   
  // do form validation here
  
  var length = +form.length.value || 0;
  var width  = +form.width.value || 0;
  var height = +form.height.value || 0;
  
  var volume = length * width * height / 1728;
  console.log(volume);
  form.total.value = isNaN(volume)? '' : volume.toFixed(3);
}
```

```html
<form id="volume">
  <fieldset><legend>Dimensions and volume</legend>
  <table id="calc-container">
    <tr>
      <td><label for="length">Length (inches): </label>
      <td><input id="length" name="length" class="calc" size="10" maxlength="5" onchange="calc()">
    <tr>
      <td><label for="width">Width (inches): </label>
      <td><input id="width" name="width" class="calc" size="10" maxlength="5" onchange="calc()">
    <tr>
      <td><label for="height">Height (inches): </label>
      <td><input id="height" name="height" class="calc" size="10" maxlength="5" onchange="calc()">
    <tr>
      <td><label for="total">Total volume (cubic feet):</label>
      <td><input id="total" name="total" readonly size="10">
  </table>
  </fieldset>
</form>
```

Comment: RobG, thanks so much. this is perfect great and WAY better coded than what I had! Thanks so much for your help with this!

Answer (score 0):

The last line in the function in Fiddle is still the old wrong one. It still does not work in Fiddle (at least for me) until I switched from "onload" to "No wrap - in <body>" on the leftmost column in Fiddle, just below the dropdown "No Library (Pure JS)". I don't know if it is the right one (I don't even have the faintest idea what it does without looking it up) but it works for me.

It also works in Firefox 41.0.2 and Chrome 46.0.2490.80 (64-bit) if I put it all from Fiddle (with the corrected line) in an HTML file.

But it lasts quiet long until you get a result and you need to click outside of the Chrome or Firefox window to get the result displayed. That means that something else is wrong here, and it is the `onchange` event. It triggers when the elements looses its focus (you don't need to click outside of the window, just elsewhere inside) and that's not the thing you want, I assume. There is another event-trigger named `oninput` and that might do what you want although it calls  `calc()` every time the user types something in.

Comment: Using events like oninput can create usability issues as they update too frequently (e.g. in this case it can result in multiplication by zero or NaN). Change is probably the most suitable event, however there should also be a "Calculate" or similar button for the user to logically transfer focus too.

Comment: Yes, the OP needs to implement some checks and balances but that needs to be done regardless of `oninput`. And if the OP adds a button the automated update of the result field makes no sense anymore. I would check for the return-key in such cases because that comes more naturally than pressing a button (the user is already using the keyboard).

Comment: thanks all so much for the responses. as the code is right now...it's actually working on site. not sure why it's not on jsfiddle. when i check it, it does; but i'll admit I don't know how to properly work jsfiddle just yet. if you run the code here, you can input data and the result will be a number with many numbers after the decimal place. is there a way to have it only show about 3 places after the decimal place? and to the incorrect code, will you please show it correctly? thanks again...

Comment: You might check `toFixed` to restrict the decimal places but that would be anther questio...wait, what? You changed the question and made my answer look completely off-topic? And the comment of RobG, too? I don't want to imply bad intent but...nah...please don't do that, better open another question. If you, please. Thank you.